# Adding users programmaticaly on a SharePoint 2010 claims based site (extranet zone)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I have a SharePoint 2010 site which has Zone Level security. The site has Windows Authentication in Default Zone while it has Claimed Based Authentication in Extranet Zone. A membership provider is used for Claimed Based site.

My my requirement is to add user of that membership provider to this claimed based site programmatically (c#).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding claim users, you need to create a pattern as:

```
i:0#.f|{MembershipProvider}|{UserName}
```

I hope the below code gives you enough details to resolve your issue:

```
string userName = "dipesh";
string membershipProvider = "MyCustomMP";
string claimUser = string.Format("i:0#.f|{0}|{1}", membershipProvider, userName);
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(claimUser);
```

Comment: Thanks Dipesh for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you say, it is working well in console application then, I believe it should be permission issue only. Please note that, the run with elevated won't work because you have hosted it as a  windows service and there won't be app pool. Correct me if I'm wrong. The user who is running the windows service should have appropriate rights for adding user. Try to run the windows service with the current logged-in  user through which you run the console application. If it is not working then, try with Farm Admin. Even if it succeed, test with other lower privileged users so that you can get exact idea of what permissions you need.
I hope you resolve your issue soon.